# Two versions of differential equation for associated Laguerre polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

When I look at Wikipedia and wolfram, the Associated Laguerre differential equation is defined
\begin{align}
x y'' + (v + 1 - x) y' + \lambda y = 0 
\end{align}
where the associated Laguerre polynomial $L_{\lambda}^v (x)$ is a solution.

However, in my textbook a slightly different differential equation is derived:
\begin{align}
x y'' + (m + 1 - x) y' + (n-m) y = 0 
\end{align}
where $L_{n}^m(x)$ is a solution.

**Question:** How does these two equations and their solutions relate?

**Attempt:** 1) I cannot find a relation just by defining $(n-m)$ as a new constant $\lambda$ since this changes the solution as well.

2. The derivation of the second equation is based on differentiating $x y'' + (1-x)y''+ n y = 0$, $m$ times and I cannot see a way to make that into the first equation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer. In case anyone else ever wonders the same thing, I can refer to "Topics in Atomic Physics", Springer, by Charles E. Burkhardt and Jacob J. Leventhal - chapter 4, section 4.

Apparently there are two different definitions of the associated Laguerre polynomials:
\begin{align}
1) \, &L_q^p (x)=\frac{d^p}{d\rho^p}[L_q (x)] \\
2) \, &L_{q-p}^p (x)=(-1)^p\frac{d^p}{d\rho^p}[L_q (x)] \\
\end{align}
Thi smakes similar polynimals have different indexing with each definition. 
So the differential equation seems to depend on the definition and you can rewrite one into the other by using 1) and 2) above.